# Performance Variation with Application to Database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I've got a database with an incredibly large record base.  I've noticed several mishaps with the legacy code, but one thing that I'm unsure of:

- `AddWithValue` :  I know the major drawback to this approach, is the object is passed to *Sql* and it will have to *infer* the type to that object you've passed.  Can be quite ambiguous and depreciated.
- `Add` : You declare the type, *Sql* doesn't infer and your reliably defining the parameter.

Aside from the reliability aspect of the *object* passed to *Sql*.  Is there a performance gain between utilizing one over another?  I can't appear to find any documentation, or evidence to support such a premise.

I know that `AddWithValue` is depreciated, but would updating all this legacy code give me any additional benefit when it currently is working?

Comment: I think that `AddWithValue` is a good approach because it lets the Database handle determining the Datatype of the parameter value that was passed in.. personally I've had / noticed zero issues with it. I have noticed that for compiling and code maintainability that using the `Add` Method can be a pain in the butt especially if the DataType changes on the Server.. then you would have to do a lot of code changes and recompiling does this make sense..?

Comment: Also if you are noticing Performance issues from one environment to the next I would personally check with the `DBA` and see if Indexes need rebuilding or If you need to Add or Remove certain Indexes..

Comment: Yeah, I notice some performance issues and he states 'It is as fast as it can be.'  Granted, we have to run with No-Lock which to me is a flag.  But they still want me to look into it on the application side, but I don't know much else I can do.  I've refactored it pretty clean, aside from removing the `AddWithValue` that is everywhere.  @DJKRAZE Yeah, that does make sense though.

Comment: may I ask why you think running with no-lock is a flag.. I can see from a DeadLocking standpoint but I agree somewhat if you have to refactor SQL to add a ton of `With No Lock` commands then possibly there is something wrong.. let me ask you this.. are there a lot of `Triggers || Cursor Logic` being used..?

Comment: Almost every one has a `No-Lock`.  Not sure about Triggers / Cursor Logic, but Congruency issues can occur.  As the thread blocks at all, it stops several jobs running.

Comment: I totally feel your pain.. been there done that.. sounds like you're on the right track in regards to what you have tried.. other issue now boils down to the scheduled jobs that run concurrently and if they use / access the same tables..then it's a fight between first come first server

Comment: I'm certain that is part of the problem, but I'm not in charge of DB.  I can only ensure the application portion is correct.

Comment: I feel ya Greg.. sounds almost like your caught between a rock and a hard place..